# What is needed for crashes to show up after Fabric Firebase migration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

There's an application, we performed the migration about a week ago. I receive Daily Summary and the Oct 11th indicates some crashes (more specifically ). When I try to view any crashes either through Fabric Crashlytics UI or Firebase Crashlytics UI I don't see anything although I try to view all versions of the said app.

[image: Firebase Screenshot_2019-10-14_11-11-23]
[image: Fabric Screenshot_2019-10-14_11-15-05]

Although the migration guide (https://fabric.io/firebase_migration) says "Continue using the Fabric Crashlytics SDK and API key in your app." and it seems no code change is needed. However I know that the Fabric and Crashlytics pods in our app are more than 2 years old. This SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54575731/292502 mentions versions, just as well https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

Also, do I have to add the `GoogleService-Info.plist` and the Firebase pod as shown in https://medium.com/@niamhpower/the-great-migration-moving-from-fabric-to-firebase-as-an-ios-developer-7b61a8b40008 ? (and I saw that `plist` in some Firebase 1-2-3 guide - I cannot find now - as well)

Can it be some missing DSYMs? We may have some OOMs (out of memory), but the numbers don't align up, I expect to see some crashes, some users reported it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like adding the dSYM files were the key for crashes to populate in the dashboard statistics. I'm still investigating with my iOS developer why it was missing or was it just in an old format (not the DWARF format the tutorials mention).

I spoke with Firebase Support about this and if there's no dSYM then they cannot symbolicate and unroll the crash call stack and right now this causes them to not contribute to the dashboard numbers. Support filed a ticket in their internal ticketing system to provide raw call stack in such cases - and potentially this would help with the crashes to populate the dashboard.

---

Also, based on this - and in accordance what the migration guide says - the Firebase pod and plist is not required to get going when you migrate from Fabric Crashlytics to Firebase Crashlytics.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know adding a `GoogleInfoPlist` is required . If it is added , delete it and move to trash (dont remove referrences) and then add it again .

1.Run your app from Xcode to install it on the simulator or your device

2.Press the Stop button in Xcode to quit it

3.Launch your app from the home screen to run it without the debugger

4.Press the “Crash” button to trigger the crash

5.Run the app again from Xcode so it can deliver the recorded crash to Crashlytics
  Within a few minutes, you should see the crash appear on your Firebase 
  Crashlytics Console.

Also make sure in your build settings you have set Debug Information Format to `DWARF with dSYM` . Also if i be honest the fabric migrationn is a little hectic  , the best way to go bout it is to select start new crashlytics project instead of migration from fabrics and download the plist and add in your project folder

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! It'll take time to go through these, in the meantime do you have any pointers / web references about the claims?

Comment: I thought this Medium Post was pretty descriptive , i used it while i was doing it , feel free to drop a comment if u come accross any issues. Also let me know if you maanged to fix it through these details .       
     https://medium.com/cr8resume/firebase-crashlytics-implementation-in-ios-app-85dd0db6b575 . Also do note that you have to set up an app on firebase using your matching bundle Ids (App Ids in apple developer) and also you have to click the "set Up crashlytics" i firebase console , and download the info plist add it run and make a connection . without that it wont work

Comment: Also do enable google analytic data , i noticed in the screenshot that it is not . Also when you run in the simulator /device once you crash the application , close Xcode . During the days i realised even if you remove the debugger if xcode is on itl take time for the crash to appear on crashlytics dashboard